# Is it possible to cross compile node.js with v8 snapshots enabled?

Tags: linux, node.js, arm, cross-compiling, v8

I'm currently cross compiling node.js for arm using the `--without-snapshot`. I would like to use v8 snapshots to improve startup speed, and wonder if it's possible to cross compile node.js with snapshots enabled? I think I remember that v8 had some kind of simulator for that end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed now with node.js version 4 where `--without-snapshot` works even when cross compiling.